# Subtract data from field - PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I've searched for an equivalent of the AGGREGATION function `sum()` in PostgreSQL but didn't find any.

I need to subtract the data of a field, from the data of another one.

The code goes as follows:

```
'''SELECT
            p.purchase_id,sum(m.Cantidad), m.state
        FROM
            stock_move m
        LEFT JOIN
            stock_picking p on (p.id=m.picking_id)
        WHERE
            p.purchase_id IN %s GROUP BY m.state, p.purchase_id'''
```

in this case `purchase_id` sums to `Cantidad` it's data, and gets stored in `stock_picking` however i need to actually subtract instead of sum, there's no subtract function in PostgreSQL as far as i know, so which function should i use to accomplish this task?

EDIT:

I have 2 modules, in OpenErp, which manage products, (sells, stock, purchases, etc), when i approve a purchase order, i need to subtract, the product quantity of the purchase from a field called `Cantidad` in another module, so, i know how to relate them in OpenErp, problem is i don't know how to subtract the quantity from this `Cantidad`.

As far as i know, the function that sums the products to be received from the `purchase order` to the `product_qty` in `stock` is as follows:

```
def desc_cert(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    if not ids: return {}
    res = {}
    for id in ids:
        res[id] = [0.0,0.0]
    cr.execute('''SELECT
            p.purchase_id,sum(m.product_qty), m.state
        FROM
            stock_move m
        LEFT JOIN
            stock_picking p on (p.id=m.picking_id)
        WHERE
            p.purchase_id IN %s GROUP BY m.state, p.purchase_id''',(tuple(ids),))
    for oid,nbr,state in cr.fetchall():
        if state=='cancel':
            continue
        if state=='done':
            res[oid][0] += nbr or 0.0
            res[oid][1] += nbr or 0.0
        else:
            res[oid][1] += nbr or 0.0
    for r in res:
        if not res[r][1]:
            res[r] = 0.0
        else:
            res[r] = 100.0 * res[r][0] / res[r][1]
    return res
```

So, i think i need a much smaller and simpler function to get this subtraction from my `Cantidad` field. In my case, i don't need any stock or picking parameter, just subtract from the `purchase_id` the products contained in it (by grouping them as this example do) and use the field from the other module called `Cantidad` instead of `product_qty`.

I hope i've explained myself.

Comment: Of course there is a function to subtract values. Please add your version of Postgres and clarify what exactly you want to subtract from what.

Comment: Thank you, the Postgres version is 9.2, and i want to subtract the "purhase_id" from "Cantidad"

Comment: In which RDBMS the code you've present gives you expected output? Can you provide details on the schema also?

Comment: Since you are grouping by `p.purchase_id`, your statement `I want to subtract the "purhase_id" from "Cantidad"` makes hardly any sense. Do you want to subtract `p.purchase_id` from the *sum* of all related `m.Cantidad`? But then again, the `LEFT JOIN` seems to go in the wrong direction. You need to provide a proper question with proper information.

Comment: Yes, from the sum of all this "Cantidad" related field , and yes, you're right, sorry i took a different exaple to show my question :(, but how can i use this function anyway? (I'm going to do another more specific question) Thank you very much

Comment: Please click "edit" right under the question to fix it. The problem can be solved easily, but do your part first.

Comment: oK :), I'll provide a better view of the entire situation, thank you!

Comment: Done, i hope i've explained myself, thank you.

Comment: Honestly, no. I am still having a hard time making sense of this. You are mixing terms for "modules" and tables or what you already have and what you want. I give up for now. Maybe somebody else understands. Table definitions might help.

Comment: NB: the where clause `p.purchase_id IN %s` will actually turn the `LEFT JOIN` into a plain join, and non-statisfying rows for "stock_move" will be discarded from the result set. As Edwin commented: it makes no sense; hard to grasp the intention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may not have realised that `sum` operates on an expression, not just a column reference:

```
SELECT sum(a - b) FROM the_table;
```

You can also use the output of `sum` for further calculations:

```
SELECT a - sum(b) FROM the_table;
```

Basic algebraic transformations show that `b - a` is equivalent to `(-a) + b`.

If this isn't what you're looking for, then based on the comments I think you might have to rephrase what you want, because this is the only thing I can guess you might be having issues with.

Comment: Yeah that was the point, sorry i couldn't explain myself better, thank you very much !!